# Emacs Slime+Allegro error 99 when running Slime, how to fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, allegro, slime

Hi) I have a problem when trying to start Slime+Allegro on Emacs, it gives me:

;Fast loading from bundle code/acldns.fasl

Error: "Local socket address not available" (errno 99) occurred while

```
   creating a passive socket on 10.15.3.181 port "(any)" .
```

[condition type: socket-error]

Screenshot of error:

[image]

IP last octet may be different, 10.15.3 part stays the same.

I have 10.5.0.0/22 subnet on my network, when I turn off network connection it runs without errors.

Is it possible to edit settings somehow or block Slime from going out to the network?

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots of errors. Paste the text instead. It's much better